# Response to the Source from Zap with Webhook Trigger

Tags: webhooks, zapier

When I have a zap of more than 1 step, and the trigger is Webhooks by Zapier with Catch Hook. When I send the response to the webhook, it provides back to the source this kind of payload response:

```
{"id": "548299ef-bb3a-4769-885a-fb001407c049", "request_id": "5f197542-b118-4fe9-9b45-f1e10b4ac710", "attempt": "5f197542-b118-4fe9-9b45-f1e10b4ac710", "status": "success"}
```

Is there a way that the connection of the Zap is kept alive and rather than providing the response up, it provides the response of the last step of the Zap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's not possible. You'll always get the json payload you posted when you send a webhook (unless you disable it, but then you just get nothing).

Long answer: No, because the zap execution happens separately from the webhook ingestion. Think of this operation less like a webserver (where the caller is waiting for a response) and more asynchronously (where the caller asks that a thing be done, the server confirms it will do it, and then the thing happens eventually).

Comment: Thanks @xavdid, do you know of a tool that receives API POST and keeps the connection alive till the steps inside it are finalized, then returns the end response back to the source that sent this API POST request?

Comment: The easiest thing is probably [runkit](https://runkit.com/docs/endpoint), which has the functionality you describe. AWS lambda will also do it, as will any webserver.

Comment: Thanks @xavdid for your advice. I reached out to runkit and i hope i can do it there.

Comment: Cool! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use here is [Make](https://make.com), as they support webhook responses.
Check out  https://www.make.com/en/help/tools/webhooks

No affiliation, I just assumed Zapier could do this (and am slightly annoyed they can't).